# What is explanation of this time difference?

Tags: windows, winforms, datetime

I have developed a Windows Form application in C#. That application shows the date and time.

To get the date and time I am using this property:

```
DateTime.Now
```

However, the time gotten in the application is 1 hour ahead of the time displayed in the Windows taskbar.

Please look at this screenshot:

[image: Time shown in application versus time shown in Windows]

You can see the time difference there.

The real time is the time shown by the application, that is, 08:38.

I know that I have problems with the time in Windows. Maybe something happened after an electricity blackout, but I am curious about that difference. I can change TimeZone settings so that Windows can show the right time, however, if I do that, always the application shows 1 hour less.

Any advice, please?

Comment: I haven't tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e07d19ab-a291-4c62-a061-dc093565f1b4/system-clock-and-datetimenow-different?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs), but looks like the same issue.

Comment: If the wrong time is the taskbar/windows one, then it's not a development-related question, is it?

Comment: DateTime object represents a time instance in a specific timezone. As you mentioned that the time in taskbar is always 1 hour ahead from the time shown in browser, this might mean that both the implementations are using different timezones to evaluate DateTime. I guess you should check into it once.

Comment: @Agam how to check DateTme timezone? UI culture and culture are both set to es-CL in web.config. if timezone set by the culture and region set by Windows are both set to Chile, why could be that different? I thought winforms culture depends on Operating System definition.

Comment: [`DateTimeOffset.Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of daylight savings, your current time zone is probably cached. A few recommendations:

Try restating the system or restarting the application.

If it still doesn't work call `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.ClearCachedData()` to reset the cached value. After this you should get the correct time.

Your clock went backward on Sunday, 7 April 2019, 12:00:00 midnight (Chile), that is why the one hour lag.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but in my case it is because the dual boot:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
DateTimeOffset.Now
```

From the MS docs:
*You can also use the DateTimeOffset.Now property to retrieve the current local date and time. It allows a local time to be expressed unambiguously as a single point in time, which in turn makes that time value portable across computers.*